SwiftUI: ScrollViewReader .scrollTo covering TextField's container
I have a 0..<x containers on screen that contains textfields. Containers have colored line width. When I am popping my keyboard, it will focus exactly on pixel where the textfield is, BUT covering visible part of containers. Is there something to adjust padding to focus to?

